# Connecting to ActiveMQ Artemis via AMQP 1.0 with Java

Tags: amqp, activemq-artemis

I am trying to connect to ActiveMQ Artemis via AMQP 1.0 with Java, but so far I am pretty unsuccessful. I tried the following client frameworks:

- org.apache.qpid:qpid-client
- org.apache.qpid:proton-j
- com.rabbitmq:amqp-client
- org.apache.qpid:qpid-amqp-1-0-client-jms

I got a `TimeoutException` error, but I'm not sure why. I pass user + password too, but still no success.

I don't want to share my code as I tried many things and it is little bit messy. My question is can somebody share / point a client code that I could use to connect to a AMQP 1.0 broker?

My question is a little bit general but I am more than happy to give more details if it is needed!

Answer (score 1):

Apache ActiveMQ Artemis speaks AMQP 1.0 if configured to do so and you want to use the Qpid JMS client which is an AMQP 1.0 JMS client implementation.  There are examples in the Artemis project source that you can reference, one such example is [here](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/tree/master/examples/protocols/amqp/queue).  Without more information on what you are doing that's about as much help as can be expected.